# Can I use PHPWord to increase the number of columns in the table from a template?

Tags: php, templates, phpword

I know that PHPWoord in "Templates processing" allows you to copy text blocks:

```
$templateProcessor->cloneBlock('CLONEME', 3);
```

Full sample: PHPWord/samples/[Sample_23_TemplateBlock.php](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/samples/Sample_23_TemplateBlock.php)

and rows in the table:

```
$templateProcessor->cloneRow('userId', 3);
```

Full sample: PHPWord/samples/[Sample_07_TemplateCloneRow.php](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/samples/Sample_07_TemplateCloneRow.php)

But is there a way to easily increase the number of columns in the table, which is stored in the template?